# How to sort results in mongoose by string length?

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, string-length

I want to sort a findOne () query by the **length** of my `iso_name` string, clearly I'm new to mongo and still learning the basics, so if you could explain me in detail I would appreciate it.
Im using mongoose ORM in NodeJs, Schema is as follows:

```
const locationSchema = new Schema({
iso_name: { type: String, require: true },
lon:  { type: Number, require: true },
lat:  { type: Number, require: true },
});
```

and the query:

```
Location.aggregate(
      [
        {$project: {
            "iso_name": 1,
            "field_length": { $strLenCP: "$iso_name" }
        }}
      ]
    )
    place = await Location.findOne(params).sort('-field_length').exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you, you can use the $sort operator to sort the length.

Configuration

```
[
  {
    "iso_name": "12"
  },
  {
    "iso_name": "1234"
  }
]
```

Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "iso_name": 1,
      "field_length": {
        $strLenCP: "$iso_name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "field_length": -1
    }
  }
])
```